# Database query to fetch data as key value pair in a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My requirement is I have a table called lmss_user and other two table custom_field_name and custom _field_value now one user in lmss_user can have multiple rows in custom_field_name and their corresponding values in custom_field_value table so I need a query that would return me all the parameters of lmss_user table along with list of key,value pair of custom_field_name,custom_field_value as the last column in a single row,currently my query gives one row for each row in custom_field_name –

```
SELECT i.EMAIL_ID,cun.NAME,cuv.VALUE
FROM lmss_user i ,
  CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME cun ,
  CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE cuv
WHERE i.id  = cun.user_id
AND cun .id = cuv.field_name_id
AND i.id    = cuv.user_id;

CREATE TABLE custom_field_name
(
id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR2(100),
user_id number(8),
CONSTRAINT pk_custom_field_name_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE custom_field_value
(
id NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
value VARCHAR2(100),
user_id number(8), field_name_id number(10),
CONSTRAINT pk_custom_field_value_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table lmss_user(
    id number(8),
    active varchar2(1),
    absent varchar2(1),
    active_period varchar2(1),
  approvals number(8),
  approver varchar2(100),
    activation_date date,
    deactivation_date date,
    activePeriod_timeZone varchar2(100),    
    prefix varchar2(100),
    first_name varchar2(100),
    middle_name varchar2(100),
    last_name varchar2(100),
    suffix varchar2(100),   
    email_Id varchar2(100), 
    work_phone varchar2(100),
    home_phone varchar2(100),   
    mobile_phone varchar2(100),
    fax varchar2(100),  
    country varchar2(100),
    address_line1 varchar2(100),
    address_line2 varchar2(100),
    city varchar2(100),
    state varchar2(100),
    postal_code varchar2(100),  
    requires_approvals varchar2(100),
    month_Of_service number(8),
    status varchar2(100),   
    classification varchar2(100),
    last_hire_date date,
    original_hire_date date,    
    ethinicity  varchar2(100),
    user_name  varchar2(100),
    gender  varchar2(100),  
    allow_reconcile  varchar2(1),
    password_text varchar2(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT i.id, i.EMAIL_ID, wmsys.wm_concat(cun.NAME||': '||cuv.VALUE) fields_and_values
  FROM lmss_user i
    join CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME cun on cun.user_id = i.id 
    join CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE cuv on cuv.user_id = i.id and cuv.field_name_id = cun.id
  group by i.id, i.email_id
```

Results:

```
 ID EMAIL_ID       FIELDS_AND_VALUES
--- -------------- -------------------------------------
  1 john@test.com  field1: jkl,field2: mno,field3: abc
  2 anne@test.com  field4: def
  3 bill@test.com  field7: ghi
```

If you have Oracle 11g or newer please use `listagg` instead `wmsys.wm_concat`.

---

Edit: Oracle 11g and newer versions:

```
SELECT i.id, i.EMAIL_ID, 
    listagg(cun.NAME||': '||cuv.VALUE, '   ') 
      within group (order by cun.name) fields_and_values
  FROM lmss_user i
    join CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME cun on cun.user_id = i.id 
    join CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE cuv on cuv.user_id = i.id and cuv.field_name_id = cun.id
  group by i.id, i.email_id
```

Results:

```
ID   EMAIL_ID        FIELDS_AND_VALUES
---  --------------  ----------------------------------------------------- 
  1  john@test.com   field1: jkl   field2: mno   field3: abc
  2  anne@test.com   field4: def
  3  bill@test.com   field7: ghi
```

Comment: So this last column here comes in as a String? For it to be mapped in java

Comment: How else can I do if the data has to be in one column? It's exactly like you wrote: _"list of key,value pair of custom_field_name,custom_field_value as the last column in a single row"_. If you need some different output please edit your question, provide output in form of simple table (like my results section), it's worth more than thousand words.

Comment: the output is absolutely correct just as I wanted !!but now I get the result only if there is any subsequent values for user in custom_field_name and custom_field_value,I also need the users without these values to with the last column as null if no value is found

Comment: Aha. So please use `left join` instead of `join` (twice).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but for single row summaries you can use pivot:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html
http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Comment: My requirement is I have a table called lmss_user and other two table custom_field_name and custom _field_value now one user in lmss_user can have multiple rows in custom_field_name and their corresponding values in custom_field_value table so I need a query that would return me all the parameters of lmss_user table along with list of key,value pair of custom_field_name,custom_field_value as the last column in a single row,currently my query gives one row for each row in custom_field_name